# How to snap divs together vertically in CSS like Pinterest have

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 4 divs floated to left, and I can see 2 in row.

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Divs are not snapping together. I mean I don't like that vertical white space :-)

Investigating Pinterest I found they use `position: absolute`, and `top`, `left`. And that's crazy, I guess some JS is responsible for calculations.

Here is JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/kurayama/4/edit

Is it possible do it with simpler CSS?

Comment: CSS column-count perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isotope is cool, but there were some conflicts with Foundation CSS framework.

Then I found Packery. It just works.

http://packery.metafizzy.co

Answer (score 1):

You need Javascript to accomplish what you are asking for, a popular library to do this is [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a simple way to do it with css alone, but I'm pretty sure that pinterest uses a script like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 not offers a solution in the form of [card-columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)